# Remap question mark, forward slash, backslash and vertical bar

Tags: autohotkey

I'm getting used to AutoHotkey and trying to remap some keys on my mini laptop.

At the moment the forward slash and question mark are on one key, the question mark being the shift character. Next to it is the backslash and vertical bar button, the vertical bar being the shift character.

I want the question mark to be on the first button without having to use the shift button and the vertical bar being the shift character. The second button needs to be the forward slash and the back slash as the shift character.

[image: SU538459 example]

I'm nearly there but can't get it right for the upper case ones. How may I achieve this?

Comment: "nearly there" = ? Paste your existing AHK script so people here can take a look and refine it.

Answer (score 2):

Karan is right, "nearly there" does not show your effort so far. I assume that you have nothing since this is so basic, you should have done in two lines.

Here you go:

```
:*:?::| ; Change question mark into pipe
:*:/::\ ; Change / into \ or what ever you want...
```